# Prevent implicit conversion but allow list initialisation?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, explicit, uniform-initialization

Let's say I have a class `FunctionWrapper` defined like this:

```
struct FunctionWrapper
{
  FunctionWrapper(std::function<void()> f);

  // ... plus other members irrelevant to the question
};
```

I'd like to prevent implicit conversions from `std::function<void()>` to `FunctionWrapper`, but allow constructing a `FunctionWrapper` using a brace initialisation syntax (that is, using list initialisation with a single argument). In other words, I'd like this:

```
void foo();
void wrap(FunctionWrapper);

wrap(foo); // (1) error
wrap({foo}); // (2) OK
wrap(FunctionWrapper{foo}); // (3) OK
```

Is there a way to achieve that? The way I've defined the class above is not it: this allows implicit conversions, so (1) compiles.

If I add `explicit` to the constructor:

```
struct FunctionWrapper
{
  explicit FunctionWrapper(std::function<void()> f);

  // ... plus other members irrelevant to the question
};
```

it doesn't help either, as that goes "too far" and disallows (2) as well as (1).

Is there a way to achieve "middle ground" and have (2) compile while (1) produces an error?

Comment: Add an explicit constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list` parameter.

Comment: you could use initializer_list but then you would have only runtime check for number of arguments... maybe template accepting const array and static_assert on template size... but that just ugly

Comment: @Hcorg wouldn't [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0rFgVYD8XKYwVlC1) require double brace initialization?

Comment: @W.F. true... too make it work `wrap` should be overloaded :/

Comment: In your first example, [only the first won't fail to compile already,](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/074c42f0137e3d6c) because the implicit conversion required from function pointer to `function<>` consumes the only allowed implicit conversion for the argument. I assume you want this to be the case even when the supplied argument is already a `function<>`?

Comment: `wrap(foo)` is already an error, and will always be an error. `wrap({foo})` already compiles. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve that?

Yes. You already have it.

```
wrap(foo);
```

For this to work, it would involve two user-defined conversions: `void(*)() --> std::function<void()> --> FunctionWrapper`, but we're only allowed up to one user-defined conversion. So this is an error and will be unless you add a separate constructor to `FunctionWrapper` to allow for it.

```
wrap({foo});
```

This is already fine, we're copy-list-initializing `FunctionWrapper` so the above limitation doesn't apply.

```
wrap(FunctionWrapper{foo});
```

This is clearly fine.

---

Note that this also provides a path forward for those cases where your first example actually worked. Let's say you had:

```
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(int ) { }
};

foo(0);           // want this to fail
foo({0});         // want this to be OK
foo(Wrapper{0});  // ... and this
```

You can't make the constructor `explicit`, since that causes `foo({0})` to fail as well. But you *can* simply add another layer of indirection with another wrapper:

```
struct AnotherWrapper {
    AnotherWrapper(int i): i{i} { }
    int i;
};

struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(AnotherWrapper ) { }
};
```

Here, `wrap(0)` fails, but `wrap({0})` and `wrap(Wrapper{0})` are both OK.